# Add two numbers safely, in C

Tags: code-golf, c

Everyone knows that C is a lovely, safe, high level programming language.  However you, as a coder are set the following task.

> Write a program to add two numbers.

- Input: Two space separated integers.
- Output: The sum of the two numbers in the input.

The twist is that your code must be 100% safe. In other words, it must behave properly no matter what the input is.  If the input is indeed two space separated integers, both of which are less than 100 digits long, it must output the sum. Otherwise, it must output an error message and quit safely.

How hard can it be after all?

General kudos will be given to pathological input cases which break other people's answers :)

The code must compile without warnings using gcc -Wall -Wextra on ubuntu.

---

**Clarification.**

- Input is from stdin.
- Horizontal whitespace is only a single space character.  There should be nothing before the first number and the input should be terminated with either newline+EOF or just EOF.
- the only valid input, specified in [Augmented Backus-Naur Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form), is:

```
    NONZERODIGIT = "1" / "2" / "3" / "4" / "5" / "6" / "7" / "8" / "9"
    POSITIVENUMBER = NONZERODIGIT *98DIGIT
    NEGATIVENUMBER = "-" POSITIVENUMBER
    NUMBER = NEGATIVENUMBER / POSITIVENUMBER / "0"
    VALIDINPUT = NUMBER SP NUMBER *1LF EOF
```

- The error message is the single letter 'E', followed by a new line.
- The code must terminate cleanly in less than 0.5s no matter what the input is.

Comment: I love how clear your spec became with a single use of the word "otherwise". Very well written (in my opinion). Too bad the challenge is only in C, but I can see why it has to be that way.

Comment: Without warnings + code-golf + C? This is bound to be interesting!

Comment: Decimal integers? "space-separated" == "whitespace-separated"?

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson Yes decimal and horizontal white space separated as you say.

Comment: stdin or command line?

Comment: Could we get a strict acceptable input format? Such as no extra whitespace (or anything not a number) before the first number, any amount of horizontal whitespace (i.e. horizontal tabs and spaces) between the two numbers, and nothing except a linefeed or a carriage return together with a linefeed after the second number?

Comment: Is the input terminated by newline+EOF or just EOF?

Comment: Since it's a code-golf, you should probably give the exact error message to display.

Comment: Also, does space-separated mean 1) separated by one character with ASCII value 32, 2) separated by an arbitrary number of character with ASCII value 32, 3) separated by any one ASCII whitespace character (32, 10, 9, possibly 13?), 4) separated by an arbitrary number of a single whitespace character from the set of ASCII whitespace characters, or 5) separeted by an arbitrary number of any combination of the set of ASCII whitespace characters?

Comment: do I understand correctly we **must** reject inputs where either number is 100 characters or longer?

Comment: @JanDvorak Yes that is right.

Comment: Which version of gcc?

Comment: @dmckee gcc 4.8.2

Comment: 100 digits? I'm pretty sure that will overflow.

Comment: Added some precision to the input definition.

Comment: Are negative numbers allowed? If so, the ABNF (with ;s) should be changed to:
    POSITIVENUMBER = 1*100DIGIT;
    NEGATIVENUMBER = "-" POSITIVENUMBER;
    NUMBER = NEGATIVE NUMBER / POSITIVENUMBER;
    VALIDINPUT = NUMBER SP NUMBER *1LF

Comment: @Scottleadley. Yes they are. Could you edit it as I can't right now?

Comment: @Lembik Also adjusted digit count from 100 to 99 to conform to "less than 100 digits long".

Comment: @ScottLeadley I am not 100% confident with ABNF so I just wanted to check but I think 001 is not a valid number. Does the ABNF you entered follow that rule? Also, the LF should be optional. Does 1*LF do that?

Comment: @Lembik 1*99DIGIT allows leading zeros. *1LF is short for 0*1LF, i.e. an optional LF.

Comment: @Lembick If you want to exclude leading zeros, use `NONZERODIGIT = "1" / "2" / "3" / "4" / "5" / "6" / "7" / "8" / "9"; POSITIVENUMBER = NONZERODIGIT *98DIGIT`

Comment: @Lembick Just realized that the current spec outlaws 0. Easiest fix (for you) is: `NUMBER = NEGATIVENUMBER / POSITIVENUMBER / "0"`. Tacking it on to POSITIVENUMBER allows -0.

Comment: @Lembick I'm sure the compiler gods will smite us for this ugly syntax graph, but it seems to be complete.

Comment: Why no warnings? gcc warnings are broken and warn about perfectly correct stuff like `putchar(c) == EOF || exit(1)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### 6610 bytes (unminified)

"Good boy" C program that meets all challenge criteria. Uses 10s complement for negative numbers. Also included, a test harness and test cases.

```
/*
Read input from STDIN. The input must conform to VALIDINPUT:

    NONZERODIGIT = "1" / "2" / "3" / "4" / "5" / "6" / "7" / "8" / "9"
    POSITIVENUMBER = NONZERODIGIT *98DIGIT
    NEGATIVENUMBER = "-" POSITIVENUMBER
    NUMBER = NEGATIVENUMBER / POSITIVENUMBER / "0"
    VALIDINPUT = NUMBER SP NUMBER *1LF EOF

Check syntax of input. If input is correct, add the two numbers and print
to STDOUT.

LSB => least significant byte
MSB => most significant byte
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <assert.h>
#define NUL ('\0')
/*
    maximum characters in VALIDINPUT:
        '-'     1
        POSITIVENUMBER  MAXDIGITS
        ' '     1
        '-'     1
        POSITIVENUMBER  MAXDIGITS
        LF      1
*/
#define MAXDIGITS (99)
#define MAXVALIDINPUT (2*MAXDIGITS+4)

void die() { printf("E\n"); exit(1); }

/*
    Add two NUMBERs and print the result to STDOUT.  The NUMBERS have
been separated into POSITIVENUMBERS and sign information.

Arguments:
    first       - pointer to LSB of 1st POSITIVENUMBER
    firstSize   - size of 1st POSITIVENUMBER
    firstNegative   - is 1st # negative?
    second      - pointer to LSB of 2nd POSITIVENUMBER
    secondSize  - size of 2nd POSITIVENUMBER
    secondNegative  - is 2nd # negative?
    carry       - carry from previous place?

Returns:
    sum[]       - sum
    addNUMBERs()    - carry to next place?

- Don't use complementDigit(popDigit(p,s),n). Side-effects generate two pops.
*/
#define popDigit(p,s) ((s)--,(*(p++)-'0'))
#define complementDigit(c,n) ((n) ? 9-(c) : (c))

#define pushSum(c) (*(--sumPointer)=(c))
#define openSum() (pushSum(NUL))
#define closeSum() ;
char    sum[MAXVALIDINPUT];
char    *sumPointer = sum+sizeof(sum);
int addNUMBERs(char *first, int firstSize, bool firstNegative,
        char *second, int secondSize, bool secondNegative,
        int previousCarry) {
    int firstDigit, secondDigit;
    int mySum;
    int myCarry;

    /*
        1st half of the problem.

        Build a stack of digits for "first" and "second"
    numbers. Each recursion of addNUMBERs() contains one digit
    of each number for that place. I.e., the 1st call holds
    the MSBs, the last call holds the LSBs.

        If negative, convert to 10s complement.
    */
    assert((firstSize > 0) && (secondSize > 0));
    if (firstSize > secondSize) {
        firstDigit = popDigit(first, firstSize);
        firstDigit = complementDigit(firstDigit, firstNegative);
        secondDigit = 0;
    } else if (secondSize > firstSize) {
        firstDigit = 0;
        secondDigit = popDigit(second, secondSize);
        secondDigit = complementDigit(secondDigit, secondNegative);
    } else {
        //  same size
        firstDigit = popDigit(first, firstSize);
        firstDigit = complementDigit(firstDigit, firstNegative);
        secondDigit = popDigit(second, secondSize);
        secondDigit = complementDigit(secondDigit, secondNegative);
    }

    //  recursion ends at LSB
    if ((firstSize == 0) && (secondSize == 0)) {
        //  if negative, add 1 to complemented LSB
        if (firstNegative) {
            firstDigit++;
        }
        if (secondNegative) {
            secondDigit++;
        }
        myCarry = previousCarry;
    } else {
        myCarry = addNUMBERs(first, firstSize, firstNegative,
            second, secondSize, secondNegative,
            previousCarry);
    }

    /*
        2nd half of the problem.

        Sum the digits and save them in first[].
    */
    mySum = firstDigit + secondDigit + ((myCarry) ? 1 : 0);
    if ((myCarry = (mySum > 9))) {
        mySum -= 10;
    }
    pushSum(mySum + '0');
    return(myCarry);
}

//  Handle the printing logic.
void addAndPrint(char *first, int firstSize, bool firstNegative,
        char *second, int secondSize, bool secondNegative,
        int previousCarry) {

    openSum();
    addNUMBERs(first, firstSize, firstNegative,
        second, secondSize, secondNegative,
        previousCarry)
    closeSum();
    if (*sumPointer<'5') {
        //  it's positive
        for (; *sumPointer=='0'; sumPointer++) {} // discard leading 0s
        //  if all zeros (sumPointer @ NUL), back up one
        sumPointer -= (*sumPointer == NUL) ? 1 : 0;
        printf("%s\n", sumPointer);
    } else {
        //  it's negative
        char    *p;

        //  discard leading 0s (9s in 10s complement)
        for (; *sumPointer=='9' && *sumPointer; sumPointer++) {}
        //  if -1 (sumPointer @ EOS), back up one
        sumPointer -= (*sumPointer == NUL) ? 1 : 0;
        for (p=sumPointer; *p; p++) {
            *p = '0' + ('9' - *p); // uncomplement
            //  special handling, +1 for last digit
            *p += (*(p+1)) ? 0 : 1;
        }
        printf("-%s\n", sumPointer);

    }
    return;
}

/*
    Lex a number from STDIN.

Arguments:
    bufferPointer - pointer to a pointer to a buffer, use as
            **buffer = c;   // put "c" in the buffer
            *buffer += 1;   // increment the buffer pointer
            (*buffer)++;    // also increments the buffer pointer

All sorts of side-effects:
    - getc(stdin)
    - ungetc(...,stdin)
    - modifies value of **bufferPointer
    - modifies value of *bufferPointer

Returns:
    lexNUMBER() - number of bytes added to *bufferPointer,
            *1 if POSITIVENUMBER,
            *-1 if NEGATIVENUMBER
    *bufferPointer - points to the LSB of the number parsed + 1
*/
#define pushc(c) (*((*bufferPointer)++)=c)
bool lexNUMBER(char **bufferPointer) {
    char    c;
    int size = 0;
    bool    sign = false;

    /* lex a NUMBER */
    if ((c=getchar()) == '0') {
        pushc(c);
        c = getchar();
        size++;
    } else {
        if (c == '-') {
            sign = true;
            c = getchar();
            // "-" isn't a digit, don't add to size
        }
        if (c == '0') {
            die();
        }
        for (size=0; isdigit(c); size++) {
            if (size >= MAXDIGITS) {
                die();
            }
            pushc(c);
            c = getchar();
        }
    }
    if (size < 1) {
        die();
    }
    ungetc(c,stdin);        // give back unmatched character
    return (sign);
}

int main() {
    int c;
    char    buffer[MAXVALIDINPUT];
    char    *bufferPointer;
    char    *first, *second;
    int firstSize, secondSize;
    bool    firstNegative, secondNegative;

    bufferPointer = buffer + 1; // hack, space for leading digit
    //  parse 1st number
    first = bufferPointer;
    firstNegative = lexNUMBER(&bufferPointer);
    firstSize = bufferPointer - first;
    *(bufferPointer++) = NUL;   // hack, space for EOS
    bufferPointer++;        // hack, space for leading digit
    //  parse separating blank
    if ((c=getchar()) != ' ') {
        die();
    }
    //  parse 2nd number
    second = bufferPointer;
    secondNegative = lexNUMBER(&bufferPointer);
    secondSize = bufferPointer - second;
    *(bufferPointer++) = NUL;   // hack, space for EOS
    //  parse end of input
    c = getchar();
    if (! ((c == EOF) || ((c == '\n') && ((c=getchar()) == EOF))) ) {
        die();
    }
    //  Some very implementation-specific massaging.
    *(--first) = '0';       // prefix with leading 0
    *(first+(++firstSize)) = NUL;   // add EOS
    *(--second) = '0';      // prefix with leading 0
    *(second+(++secondSize)) = NUL; // add EOS
    //  add and print two arbitrary precision numbers
    addAndPrint(first, firstSize, firstNegative,
        second, secondSize, secondNegative, false);
    return(0);
}
```

Here's a little test harness and a few test cases to get you started. Feel free to tear out the excessive use of perl. The system it was developed on didn't have a modern bash.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#   testharness.sh
#
# Use as: bash testharness.sh program_to_be_tested < test_data
#
# Each line in the test data file should be formatted as:
#
#   INPUT = bash printf string, must not contain '"'
#   OUTPUT = perl string, must not contain '"'
#           (inserted into the regex below, use wisely)
#   TESTNAME = string, must not contain '"'
#   GARBAGE = comments or whatever you like
#   INPUTQUOTED = DQUOTE INPUT DQUOTE
#   OUTPUTQUOTED = DQUOTE OUTPUT DQUOTE
#   TESTQUOTED = DQUOTE TESTNAME DQUOTE
#   TESTLINE = INPUTQUOTED *WSP OUTPUTQUOTED *WSP TESTQUOTED GARBAGE
TESTPROGRAM=$1
TMPFILE=testharness.$$
trap "rm $TMPFILE" EXIT
N=0         # line number in the test file
while read -r line; do
    N=$((N+1))
    fields=$(perl -e 'split("\"",$ARGV[0]);print "$#_";' "$line")
    if [[ $fields -lt 5 ]]; then
        echo "skipped@$N"
        continue
    fi
    INPUT=$(perl -e 'split("\"",$ARGV[0]);print "$_[1]";' "$line")
    OUTPUT=$(perl -e 'split("\"",$ARGV[0]);print "$_[3]";' "$line")
    TESTNAME=$(perl -e 'split("\"",$ARGV[0]);print "$_[5]";' "$line")
    printf -- "$INPUT" | $TESTPROGRAM > $TMPFILE
    perl -e "\$t='^\\\s*$OUTPUT\\\s*\$'; exit (<> =~ \$t);" < $TMPFILE
    if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then     # perl -e "exit(0==0)" => 1
        echo "ok $TESTNAME"
    else
        echo -n "failed@$N $TESTNAME," \
            "given: \"$INPUT\" expected: \"$OUTPUT\" received: "
        cat $TMPFILE
        echo
    fi
done
```

A small set of test cases:

```
"0 0"       "0" "simple, 0+0=0"
"1 1"       "2" "simple, 1+1=2"

""      "E" "error, no numbers"
"0"     "E" "error, one number"
"0  0"      "E" "error, two/too much white space"
"0 0 "      "E" "error, trailing characters"
"01 0"      "E" "error, leading zeros not allowed"

"-0 0"      "E" "error, negative zero not allowed
"0 -0"      "E" "error, negative zero not allowed here either

"1 1\n"     "2" "LF only allowed trailing character

"\0001 1\n"    "E" "error, try to confuse C string routines #1"
"1\00 1\n"  "E" "error, try to confuse C string routines #2"
"1 \0001\n"    "E" "error, try to confuse C string routines #3"
"1 1\000\n"    "E" "error, try to confuse C string routines #4"
"1 1\n\000"    "E" "error, try to confuse C string routines #5"

"-1 -1"     "-2"    "add all combinations of -1..1 #1"
"-1 0"      "-1"    "add all combinations of -1..1 #2"
"-1 1"      "0" "add all combinations of -1..1 #3"
"0 -1"      "-1"    "add all combinations of -1..1 #4"
"0 0"       "0" "add all combinations of -1..1 #5"
"0 1"       "1" "add all combinations of -1..1 #6"
"1 -1"      "0" "add all combinations of -1..1 #7"
"1 0"       "1" "add all combinations of -1..1 #8"
"1 1"       "2" "add all combinations of -1..1 #9"

"0 123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789" "123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789" "0+99 digits should work"

"100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "99 digits+99 digits should work"

"500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "test for accumulator overflow"

"-123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789 0" "-123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789" "0+negative 99 digits work"

"-100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 -100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "-200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "99 digits+99 digits (both negative) should work"

"-500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 -500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "-1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "test for negative accumulator overflow"

"1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890 0" "E" "error, 100 digits"
```

Comment: Fixed the last two large negative number tests. They weren't testing negative numbers.

Comment: I get lots of warnings with -Wall -Wextra from your code.

Comment: @Lembik Other posters can feel free to copy the lexer and fix the compiler warnings. It does implement a safe lexer & does do arbitrary precision arithmetic (sort of). I spent some effort on the mal-coding (see comments in the code), so you should get lots of compiler warnings. How about a gold star for the lexer and a swift boot in the rear for disregarding the other criteria?

Comment: That seems very reasonable :) Consider it done.

Comment: @Lembick Replaced with all C solution using 10s complement arithmetic. Moved "bad example" solution using `bc` to separate answer.

Answer (score 3):

### 289

**EDIT** : This code works only for positive integers. The rules has changed since I post this answer.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int r[101],s;void x(int i){r[i]|=32;if(r[i]>41)r[i+1]++,r[i]-=10,x(i+1);}void f(int b){int c=getchar();if(c!=b){if(s>99||c<48||c>57)exit(puts("E"));f(b);r[s]+=c-48;x(s++);}}int main(){f(32);s=0;f(10);for(s=100;s--;)if(r[s])putchar(r[s]+16);return 0;}
```

Ungolfed and commented version :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//global variables are automatically init to zero
int result[101]; //101 because 2 numbers of 100 digits can give a 101-digits result
int currentNumber;

void reportAddition(int i) {
    result[i]|=0x20; //flag "active" value, 6th bit
    if(result[i]>9+0x20) {
        result[i+1]++;
        result[i]-=10;
        reportAddition(i+1);
    }
}

void addNumber(int endingChar) {
    int c=getchar();
    if(c!=endingChar) {
        if(currentNumber>99||c<'0'||c>'9') //error
            exit(puts("Error"));
        addNumber(endingChar);
        result[currentNumber]+=c-'0';
        reportAddition(currentNumber); //handle case when addition give a value greater than 9
        currentNumber++;
    }
}

int main() {

    addNumber(' '); //add first number
    currentNumber=0;
    addNumber('\n'); //add second

    for(currentNumber=100;currentNumber--;)
        if(result[currentNumber])
            putchar(result[currentNumber]+'0'-0x20); //display char
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you reject inputs longer than 99 digits? It seems to me you should.

Comment: @JanDvorak, yes I do.

Comment: I get several compilation warnings: `./tmp.c: In function ‘f’:
./tmp.c:3:1: warning: suggest parentheses around comparison in operand of ‘|’ [-Wparentheses]
./tmp.c:3:1: warning: suggest parentheses around comparison in operand of ‘|’ [-Wparentheses]
./tmp.c: In function ‘main’:
./tmp.c:3:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]`

Comment: I didn't mean to specify the numbers were positive. Apologies.

Comment: @ace I don't have this warning here, is replacing `(s>99|c<48|c>57)` by `(s>99||c<48||c>57)` fix that ?

Comment: @Michael it fixes the first two warnings, but you still need a return value in `main`

Comment: I get no warnings now.

Answer (score 2):

### 442

It is quite long, so I may golf it down further during the weekend. Assumes input is from stdin, EOF-terminated (without newline), separator is only one character of ASCII value 32 (that is, `' '` character).

```c
#include<stdio.h>
char a[102],b[102],c[102],*p=a,d;int i,j=101,l,L,k,F=1;int main(){while(~(k=getchar())){if(47<k&&k<58){p[i++]=k;if(i==101)goto f;}else if(k==32&&F)p=b,l=i,F=0,i=0;else goto f;}L=i;for(i=(l<L?l:L)-1;i+1;i--){c[j]=(L<l?b[i]-48+a[i+l-L]:a[i]-48+b[i+L-l]);if(c[j--]>57)c[j]++,c[j+1]-=10;}for(i=(L<l?l-L-1:L-l-1);i+1;i--)c[j--]=(L<l?a[i]:b[i]);for(i=0;i<102;i++)if(c[i]&&(c[i]-48||d))d=putchar(c[i]);return 0;f:return puts("E");}
```

The error message will be a single character 'E', followed by a new line.

With newlines and a little bit of indentation added: (a readable version follows, so feel free to skip over here)

```c
#include<stdio.h>
char a[102],b[102],c[102],*p=a,d;
int i,j=101,l,L,k,F=1;
int main(){
    while(~(k=getchar())){
        if(47<k&&k<58){
            p[i++]=k;
            if(i==101)goto f;
        }else if(k==32&&F)p=b,l=i,F=0,i=0;
        else goto f;
    }
    L=i;
    for(i=(l<L?l:L)-1;i+1;i--){
        c[j]=(L<l?b[i]-48+a[i+l-L]:a[i]-48+b[i+L-l]);
        if(c[j--]>57)c[j]++,c[j+1]-=10;
    }
    for(i=(L<l?l-L-1:L-l-1);i+1;i--)c[j--]=(L<l?a[i]:b[i]);
    for(i=0;i<102;i++)if(c[i]&&(c[i]-48||d))d=putchar(c[i]);
    return 0;
    f:return puts("E");
}
```

The readable version (some statements are slightly altered to make it more readable, but what they do should be the same):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
char num1[102],num2[102],sum[102]; //globals initialised to 0
char *p=num1;
int outputZero=0, noExtraSpace=1;
int i=0, j=101, len1, len2, ch;
#define min(x,y) (x<y?x:y)
int main(){
    while((ch=getchar())!=-1) { //assumes EOF is -1
        if('0'<=ch && ch<='9') {
            p[i]=ch;
            i++;
            if(i==101) goto fail; //if input too long
        } else if(ch==' ' && noExtraSpace) {
            p=num2;
            len1=i;
            noExtraSpace=0;
            i=0;
        } else goto fail; //invalid character
    }
    len2=i;
    for(i=min(len1, len2)-1; i>=0; i--) {
        //add each digit when both numbers have that digit
        sum[j]=(len2<len1?num2[i]-'0'+num1[i+len1-len2]:num1[i]-'0'+num2[i+len2-len1]);
        if(sum[j]>'9') { //deal with carries
            sum[j-1]++;
            sum[j]-=10;
        }
        j--;
    }
    for(i=(len2<len1?len1-len2-1:len2-len1-1); i>=0; i--) {
        //copy extra digits when one number is longer than the other
        sum[j]=(len2<len1?num1[i]:num2[i]);
        j--;
    }
    for(i=0; i<102; i++) {
        if(sum[i] && (sum[i]-'0' || outputZero)) {
            putchar(sum[i]);
            outputZero=1;
            //if a digit has been output, the remaining zeroes must not be leading
        }
    }
    return 0;
    fail:
    puts("Error");
    return 0;
}
```

<sub><sub><sub>The `goto fail;` thing is here to mock Apple.</sub></sub></sub>

The version of gcc I used is `gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3`, and there are no warnings.

Comment: What about -1 1 as input.

Comment: @Lembik prints error message because the input should be "Two space separated **positive** integers."

Comment: Oh sorry I mucked that up. I thought I had changed that.

Comment: Currently your code always outputs E for me. I tried "1 1" for example. Also could you make the input come from stdin?

Comment: @Lembik The input is from stdin (`getchar()` always gets from stdin). It is assumed to be EOF-terminated **without newline**. You can test this, either by entering [1][space][1][Ctrl+D][Ctrl+D], or `echo -n '1 1' | program`

Comment: Thanks.  The spec says " with either newline+EOF or just EOF" and that didn't even change late on :)

Answer (score 0):

#### 633 bytes

"Bad boy" C program that meets half the challenge. Abuses C, throws lots of warnings, but works ... sort of. Arbitrary precision arithmetic is actually done by `bc`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#define g() getc(stdin)
#define z(c) b[i++]=c,b[i]='\0'
x(){puts("E\n");exit(1);}main(){int c,y=0,i=0;char b[232]="",*h="echo ",*t=" | bc -q | tr -d '\\\\\\012'";strcat(b,h);i=strlen(h);if((c=g())=='0'){z(c);y=1;c=g();}else{if(c=='-'){z(c);c=g();}c!='0'||x();ungetc(c,stdin);for(y=0;isdigit(c=g());y++){z(c);y<99||x();}}y>0||x();c==' '||x();z('+');y=0;if((c=g())=='0'){z(c);y=1;c=g();}else{if(c=='-'){z(c);c=g();}c!='0'||x();do{if(!isdigit(c))break;z(c);y++;y<=99||x();}while(c=g());}y>0||x();strcat(b+i,t);i+=strlen(t);if(!((c==-1)||((c=='\n')&&((c=g())==-1))))x();system(b);}
```

Unminified version

```
/*
Read input from STDIN. The input must conform to VALIDINPUT:

    NONZERODIGIT = "1" / "2" / "3" / "4" / "5" / "6" / "7" / "8" / "9"
    POSITIVENUMBER = NONZERODIGIT *98DIGIT
    NEGATIVENUMBER = "-" POSITIVENUMBER
    NUMBER = NEGATIVENUMBER / POSITIVENUMBER / "0"
    VALIDINPUT = NUMBER SP NUMBER *1LF EOF

Check syntax of input. If input is correct, use the shell command
"echo NUMBER+NUMBER | bc -q" to do the arbitrary precision integer arithmetic.

NB, this solution requires that the "normal" bc be 1st in the PATH.


    Fun C language features used:
    - ignore arguments to main()
    - preprocessor macros
    - pointer arithmetic
    - , operator
    - ?: operator
    - do-while loop
    - for loop test does input
    - implicit return/exit
    - short is still a type!
    - ungetc()
    - use int as bool and 0 & 1 as magic numbers
    - implicit type coersion

5/5/14, Stop fighting the syntax graph. Get rid of "positive" flag.
*/
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MAXDIGITS (99)
#define pushc(c) (buffer[index++]=c,buffer[index]='\0')
#define pushs(s) (strcat(buffer+index,s),index+=strlen(s))

int die() { printf("E\n"); exit(1); }

int main () {
    int c;
    /*
    buffer budget:
    5               "echo "
    1+MAXDIGITS (include "-")   NUMBER
    1               "+"
    1+MAXDIGITS (include "-")   NUMBER
    25              " | bc -q | tr -d '\\\012'"
    1               NUL
    */
    char    buffer[5+1+MAXDIGITS+1+1+MAXDIGITS+25+1] = "";
    short   index = 0;
    short   digits;

    pushs("echo ");
    // parse 1st number
    digits = 0;
    if ((c=getchar()) == '0') {
        pushc(c);
        digits = 1;
        c = getchar();
    } else {
        if (c == '-') {
            // "-" doesn't count against digits total
            pushc(c);
            c = getchar();
        }
        (c != '0') || die();
        ungetc(c,stdin);
        for (digits=0; isdigit(c=getchar()); digits++) {
            pushc(c);
            (digits<MAXDIGITS) || die();
        }
    }
    (digits>=1) || die();
    // parse separating blank
    (c == ' ') || die();
    pushc('+');
    // parse 2nd number
    digits = 0;
    if ((c=getchar()) == '0') {
        pushc(c);
        digits = 1;
        c = getchar();
    } else {
        if (c == '-') {
            // "-" doesn't count against digits total
            pushc(c);
            c = getchar();
        }
        (c != '0') || die();
        do {
            if (!isdigit(c)) {
                break;
            }
            pushc(c);
            digits++;
            (digits<=MAXDIGITS) || die();
        } while(c=getchar());
    }
    (digits>=1) || die();
    pushs(" | bc -q | tr -d '\\\\\\012'");
    // parse end of input
    if (! ((c == EOF) || ((c == '\n') && ((c=getchar()) == EOF))) ) {
        die();
    }
    // add two arbitrary precision numbers and print the result to STDOUT
    system(buffer);
}
```